# Use curl to post data to a form?

Tags: forms, curl

I have a form like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart-form-data" name="my_form" action="http://www.sms-online.web.id/kirim" >

<input class="field text small" type="text" maxlength="20" name="Phonenumbers" />
<br />
<textarea rows="5" cols="20" onKeyPress=check_length(this.form); onKeyDown=check_length(this.form); name=Text ></textarea>
<br />
<input id="saveForm" class="btTxt" type="submit" value="KIRIM" name="TOMBOL" />
</form>
```

Let's say that form is located at `http://myurl.com/form` How do I post to that form **and then click the submit button**? and what my file should look like? should it look like this or not:

```
Phonenumbers=08111111
Text=SMScontent
```

I already tried this but didn't work:

```
curl --data "Phonenumbers=0811111&text=testing&TOMBOL=KIRIM" http://myurl.com/form
```

I tried **@sputnick** suggestion but got the following error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
<head><title> 301 Moved Permanently
</title></head>
<body style="color: #444; margin:0;font: normal 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; height:100%; background-color: #fff;">
<div style="height:auto; min-height:100%; ">     <div style="text-align: center; width:800px; margin-left: -400px; position:absolute; top: 30%; left:50%;">
        <h1 style="margin:0; font-size:150px; line-height:150px; font-weight:bold;">301</h1>
<h2 style="margin-top:20px;font-size: 30px;">Moved Permanently
</h2>
<p>The document has been permanently moved.</p>
</div></div><div style="color:#f0f0f0; font-size:12px;margin:auto;padding:0px 30px 0px 30px;position:relative;clear:both;height:100px;margin-top:-101px;background-color:#474747;border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) inset;">
<br>Proudly powered by  <a style="color:#fff;" href="http://www.litespeedtech.com/error-page">LiteSpeed Web Server</a><p>Please be advised that LiteSpeed Technologies Inc. is not a web hosting company and, as such, has no control over content found on this site.</p></div></body></html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760655/how-to-post-data-to-server-with-curl#

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the `Text` field (need to capitalize) so :

```
 curl -d "Phonenumbers=0811111&Text=testing&TOMBOL=KIRIM" http://myurl.com/form
 #                             ^
```

and to do such things, use cookies and a fake user-agent. Check

```
man curl
```

Comment: You have to **follow redirections** and apply my recommendations (not just the typo)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-F` flag to POST multipart-form-data as in:

```
curl -F "Phonenumbers=0811111&Text=testing&TOMBOL=KIRIM" http://myurl.com/form
```

Comment: With `--data` it's an implicit POST

Comment: yes, but not the `Content-Type` is then not multipart-form-data but `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

[`curl`](https://blog.eduguru.in/php/curl-in-html-forms-use-of-curl)`--data "dob=2018&press=OK" http://blog.eduguru.in/testapp.cgi`